# how to write test for this function

Tags: scala, grpc

This is a grpc intercept function which return a Listener, how can I write a test for this?

```
override def interceptCall[ReqT, RespT](call: ServerCall[ReqT, RespT], requestHeaders: Metadata, next: ServerCallHandler[ReqT, RespT]): ServerCall.Listener[ReqT] = {
        next.startCall(new SimpleForwardingServerCall[ReqT, RespT](call) {
             override def sendHeaders(responseHeaders: Metadata): Unit = {
                responseHeaders.put(CUSTOM_HEADER_KEY, "customRespondValue")
            }
```

Comment: What have you tried by yourself? What issue/error did you encounter?

Comment: I would use an integration test that actually calls the remote service and asserts that  the right header is in the response. I don't think you would get much value out of a unit test for something so simple.